# WPML with Woocommerce plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, woocommerce, wpml

I installed `WPML` for my `WP` site and Woocommerce Product Print to create a `PDF` document from a product page. My problem is that, the `PDF` plugin works for the Italian version, but, for the English version the global variable `$post` in Woocommerce Product Print is empty.
Have I set some thing in the backend of my site?
Can you help me please?

Comment: @jacefarm Thats not right, on StackExchange's WordPress this thread is just going to get on-hold and deleted, as it's using a plugin… So please delete your comment.

Comment: @AlessandroVallini Your question is very vague, please update it, adding which plugin you are using for PDF. The more details you add, better are your chances to get helped. Afterwards, may be you should try with `global $woocommerce, $product;` instead of `global $post;`…

Comment: Agree with both @LoicTheAztec's comments. This will get kicked back over to here from the WordPress stack as it isn't related to WP core. However, it's very also too vague to answer.